# I cant get the last word in the span to show and stay on screen after the scroll completes

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I can get the span to scroll throw all the words but the lastWord.  I need that word to stay on the screen but I cant get it to show or stay.

The scroll works fine other than the lastWord. I expect it to show since I have the opacity set to 0 and in the fade in its set to 1.

I am not sure what I am missing with this code.

```
<div id="scrollTextContainer">
  <span id="harderWord"><h2>Harder</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Play</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Think</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Learn</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Train</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Fight</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Recover</h></span>
  <span class="scrollWord lastWord"><h2>Play</h2></span>
</div>

<style>
#scrollTextContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: show;
}

#harderWord {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.scrollWord {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 0;
}

.harderWord, span {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 2.5; 
}

.scrollWord, span {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 2.5;
}

.lastWord span {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

  
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById("scrollTextContainer");
  var harderWord = document.getElementById("harderWord");
  var scrollWords = document.getElementsByClassName("scrollWord");
  var lastWord = document.getElementsByClassName("lastWord")[0];

  // Fade in the harder word at 20 seconds and always show it
  setTimeout(function() {
    harderWord.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 10000);

  // Fade in and out the other words at specified intervals
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[0].style.opacity = 1;
  }, 16000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[0].style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[1].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }, 24000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[1].style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[2].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }, 30000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[2].style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[3].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }, 36000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[3].style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[4].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }, 41000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[4].style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[5].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }, 46000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollWords[5].style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      lastWord.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }, 50000);
};


</script>
```

Comment: You can do this effect with only css: animation-delay

Comment: Have you considered doing the whole thing with keyframes (CSS animation)? It might make the whole thing use less CPU.

Comment: As this was caused by a typo voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not closing correctly 2nd last `<h2>` element inside `<span>`.

change

```
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Recover</h></span>
```

to

```
 <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Recover</h2></span>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/zc86kwL5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the way you are selecting the lastword. Should be span.lastword. It's the span with that class that you are interested in, not a span schild of an element with that class.

(You also have a typo - h instead of h2 in the second last word element.)

```html
<div id="scrollTextContainer">
  <span id="harderWord"><h2>Harder</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Play</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Think</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Learn</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Train</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Fight</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord"><h2>Recover</h2></span>
  <span class="scrollWord lastWord"><h2>Play</h2></span>
</div>

<style>
  #scrollTextContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    overflow: show;
  }
  
  #harderWord {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .scrollWord {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .harderWord,
  span {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 2.5;
  }
  
  .scrollWord,
  span {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 2.5;
  }
  
  span .lastWord {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 2.5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("scrollTextContainer");
    var harderWord = document.getElementById("harderWord");
    var scrollWords = document.getElementsByClassName("scrollWord");
    var lastWord = document.getElementsByClassName("lastWord")[0];

    // Fade in the harder word at 20 seconds and always show it
    setTimeout(function() {
      harderWord.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 10000);

    // Fade in and out the other words at specified intervals
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[0].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 16000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[0].style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollWords[1].style.opacity = 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 24000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[1].style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollWords[2].style.opacity = 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 30000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[2].style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollWords[3].style.opacity = 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 36000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[3].style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollWords[4].style.opacity = 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 41000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[4].style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollWords[5].style.opacity = 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 46000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollWords[5].style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        lastWord.style.opacity = 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 50000);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, it was the typo causing the error.  once that was fixed the scroll was correct and stopped on Play. Thank you so much.